# C# Asynchronous TCP Listener Socket does not accept connections

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

I have tried to make my first asynchronous socket program on C#, despite no error on the code, it does not accept connections. I have checked by Telnet.
this is my TCP server code:
I have just seen some samples on the internet but I could not find my problem, I believe that some thing else should add to my code.

```
 class Program
{
    static byte[] Mybuffer = new byte[4096];
   static TcpClient tc = new TcpClient();
     
    private static void PrintUsageInfo()
    {

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TcpListener tl = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.141"), 8008);
        tl.Start();
        tl.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnCompleteTCP, tl);


    }



    static void OnCompleteReadData(IAsyncResult isa)
    {
        int countreadbytes = 0;
        
        
        try
        {
            //TcpClient tc;
            tc = (TcpClient)isa.AsyncState;
            countreadbytes = tc.GetStream().EndRead(isa);
            if (countreadbytes==0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("USER Disconnected");
                //client disconnect
                return;
            }
            
            //continue to get data
            tc.GetStream().BeginRead(Mybuffer, 0, Mybuffer.Length, OnCompleteReadData, tc);
            Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Mybuffer));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
    static void OnCompleteTCP(IAsyncResult isa)
    {
        
        TcpListener tcpl = (TcpListener)isa.AsyncState;
        
       
       
        tc=tcpl.EndAcceptTcpClient(isa);
        tc.GetStream().BeginRead(Mybuffer, 0, Mybuffer.Length, OnCompleteReadData, tc);
        
    }
}
```

So what is the problem?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall thing, or a bind address thing; initially, try to use `IPAddress.Any` as first argument. If it works, great. If it doesn't, turn off firewall temporarily. If it works, make a firewall rule for port 8008

Comment: TNX. turning off firewall was the first measure that I have taken to solve this but it does not work even with IpAddress.Any! I think it should be something very simple that I could not find

Comment: Can you telnet to any other service on the target machine? `netstat -a` will list the listening ports

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Caius Jard i have checked the netstat -a to see all listening ports and my port was not there. So I found out that this might be a problem on running process. I put the BeginAcceptTcpclient on a while(true) loop and it is working well now!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TcpListener tl = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8008);
        tl.Start();
        while (true) { tl.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnCompleteTCP, tl); }


    }
```